# Show "WAIT or "LOADING" - Lable while creating new ViewController

Tags: ios, label, push, show, viewcontroller

When pushing a button, I create a new ViewController and push it.
This takes 1,5 seconds. I want to display a "WAIT" or "LOADING" label, while creating the ViewController, but it would not been displayed.

I tried to add an hidden label, but the view will not show it, when I set `hidden=NO`. Also a refresh of the view does not work. Any ideas?

```
- (IBAction)pushNext:(id)sender {
    //    UILabel *ll = (UILabel *) [self.view viewWithTag:7];
    //    ll.hidden = NO;
    //    label[7].hidden = NO;
    ViewController *gameViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController"];
    gameViewController.level = _nextLevel;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:gameViewController animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't take that much. Move things inside gameViewController from `viewDidLoad` to `viewDidAppear`.

And after that use:

```
// Create loading UIActivityIndicator
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    // All viewDidAppear code

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        // Remove loading
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you, but that results in a blank (white) view. It shows the elements of my storyboard, but not my "main"- subview. Maybe your idea doing things async could be the solution. I will try to move the creation of viewcontroller in a dispatch_async. When I comment out pushViewController my "WAIT"-label appears. It seems like a timing problem?

Comment: No.. when you try to load the gameViewController the whole app freeze because you maybe have a request there or a big job for procesor. If you move the the thing that takes time in background.. you will have a smooth pass to the gameViewController and after the job is done.. other elements should appear